# Prealgebra-number theory

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Given a positive integer $N$. Deleting the last digit of $N$ will decrease it by $2011$. What is $N$?

I know the answer, but can anyone show the working?

Comment: For a question like this, "I tried and failed until I found this number which worked" is enough working to show. But you can be clever about where you start trying. How many digits should $N$ have, for instance? What should the first digit be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N = \overline{Ax}$. One then has $$\overline{Ax} - A = 2011.$$
$$9A + x = 2011.$$

So, $2011-x = 9A$. Try $x$ from 0 to 9, you will get $A = 223$, $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $N=10x+a$ for some $0\le a\le 9$

Answer (score 0):

X + 2011 = 10X + e where e is a one digit error
X = 2011/9 - e and e is still an error, not sure if is the same as the other e
X = 223 + another e I am ignoring
So 223e - 223 = 2011, and this e I will solve.  It is 4.
The answer is 2234.
Simple, more puzzle than math, and it can be solved with 7th grade notation.

Comment: Apologies that my carriage returns were ignored. It is hard to read.